# How do you disable the right mouse click inside a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

How do you disable the right mouse click inside a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just set the context menu to a new `ContextMenu`

```
    textBoxt1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
```

Answer (score 3):

A neater solution might be to just disable the 'ShortcutsEnabled' property of the textbox as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083475/how-to-remove-the-default-context-menu-of-a-textbox-control-c-sharp).

It would be a shame both scientifically and philosophically to create a whole object that has absolutely no purpose in life.