# How to remove the default context menu of a TextBox Control? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to remove the default context menu of a `TextBox` Control?

[image]

Is there a property to disable it?
Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to upset the usability gods?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible, and how to do it.. hehe thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also set the `ShortcutsEnabled` property to `false`. This removes the default context menu and all clipboard functionality. I presume that's why you're trying to suppress the menu? I can't think of any good reason other than purposefully preventing your users from using copy/paste.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible, and how to do it.. hehe thanks Sir Bradley

Comment: It is unintuitivly. I would not have found this, without your help.

Answer (score 18):

Try setting the ContextMenu property of the TextBox to a dummy, empty ContextMenu instance.

Comment: ... and this also allows user to use shortcut keys such as Ctrl + X, Ctrl + C ... while setting `ShortcutsEnabled = false` will disable those shortcuts. I think this should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ContextMenu blah = new ContextMenu();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.ContextMenu = blah;
    }
}
```

Comment: textBox1.ContextMenu = New ContextMenu()