# Disable default menu of vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, contextmenustrip

I have a few question. Is it possible to disable this menu when i press rightclick?

[image]

I have my  own context menu strip and my problem is when i press right click that default menu is shown. then i will press left click to remove that default menu then my own menu strip will now be visible.

Is there any way to disable that default menu and directly show my menu strip when i right click?

Note: Default Menu will be shown if editing is on going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Shortcuts enabled = false in the properties of the textbox

Comment: I think my question is a duplicate. I already found my answer for textbox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083475/how-to-remove-the-default-context-menu-of-a-textbox-control-c-sharp

Comment: for datagridview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309613/removing-the-default-context-menu-when-editing-a-cell-in-datagridview

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the `Form_Load` where the `TextBox` is placed:

`txtBox1.ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip`

Declaring a new `ContextMenuStrip` is like replacing the old one with a new "blank" one.

Comment: I think my question is a duplicate. I already found my answer for textbox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083475/how-to-remove-the-default-context-menu-of-a-textbox-control-c-sharp

Comment: for datagridview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309613/removing-the-default-context-menu-when-editing-a-cell-in-datagridview